# Вытащить содержимое

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой длинный html:

```
    <div id="selection"></div>
<div id="sel">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="name_inp" value="val1" id="val1"></td>
        <td><label for="val1"><nobr><span>first label</span></nobr></label></td>
        <td><label for="val1"><nobr>second label</nobr></label></td>
        <td><label for="val1"><nobr>third label</nobr></label></td>
        <td><label for="val1">fourth label</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="name_inp" value="val2" id="val2"></td>
        <td><label for="val2"><nobr><span>first label</span></nobr></label></td>
        <td><label for="val2"><nobr>second label</nobr></label></td>
        <td><label for="val2"><nobr>third label</nobr></label></td>
        <td><label for="val2">fourth label</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="name_inp" value="val3" id="val3"></td>
        <td><label for="val3"><nobr><span>first label</span></nobr></label></td>
        <td><label for="val3"><nobr>second label</nobr></label></td>
        <td><label for="val3"><nobr>third label</nobr></label></td>
        <td><label for="val3">fourth label</label></td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

А вопрос такой: как, в зависимости от выбранного `radio`, вытащить текст "third label" и "fourth label" и поместить его в первый `div`? Текст генерирует `php`, к уникальному значению не привязаться.
Применять `next()`, думаю, не тот случай. Какой-то `filter()`? Не могу сообразить, как лучше.

Значение получаю так:

```
var val_sel = $('#sel input:radio:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подойдет?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').bind('click', function() {
        $('#selection').html($('label[for="' + $(this).val() + '"]').eq(2).html());
    });
});
```

Объясню:
`$('label[for=' + $(this).val() + ']')` - ищет все тэги `label`, относящиеся к `value` выбранного радио
`.eq(2)` - берет третий из найденных
`.html()` - выделяет его содержимое
`$('#selection').html([что-то])` - заносит `[что-то]` внутрь элемента с `id=selection`

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Только двойные кавычки пропали: $('#selection').html($('label[for="' + $(this).val() + '"]').eq(2).html());